# SDL 1.2 SDL_FillRect on Mac OSX

Tags: c++, c, xcode, macos, sdl

I want to use SDL 1.2 on Mac OS X in Xcode.
I don't have any problem creating a window :

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>

void pause()
{
    int continuer = 1;
    SDL_Event event;

    while (continuer)
    {
        SDL_WaitEvent(&event);
        switch(event.type)
        {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                continuer = 0;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SDL_Surface *ecran = NULL;

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    ecran = SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE);
    if (ecran == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Impossible de charger le mode vidéo : %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    SDL_WM_SetCaption("Ma super fenêtre SDL !", NULL);

    pause();

    SDL_Quit();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But when I try to add a color or an image on my window nothing happens. The window stays gray.

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>

void pause()
{
    int continuer = 1;
    SDL_Event event;

    while (continuer)
    {
        SDL_WaitEvent(&event);
        switch(event.type)
        {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                continuer = 0;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SDL_Surface *ecran = NULL;

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    ecran = SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE);
    if (ecran == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Impossible de charger le mode vidéo : %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    }
    SDL_WM_SetCaption("Ma super fenêtre SDL !", NULL);
    SDL_FillRect(ecran, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(ecran->format, 17, 206, 112));

    SDL_Flip(ecran);
    pause();

    SDL_Quit();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.